# How do you access data in an html element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know this is a stupid question. But holy crap, it's just not working. Here is an extremely basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="test">Test</p>
        <script>
            let test = document.getElementById("test").value
            alert(test)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I get a variable that contains the text inside of the paragraph? This code does not work. There is apparently no .value attribute for the paragraph object. Why is that? I'm using visual studio code and running it on google chrome if that matters.

Comment: try .innerText or .innerHTML instead of .value

Comment: @bturner1273 is right. I've added a comment with a bit of a description and links to documentation

Comment: @bturner1273 `.innerHTML` should only be used when a) there is HTML to be parsed and b) that HTML is under the developer's control. Instead, `.textContent` should be used here.

Answer (score 1):

`Element.value` doesn't refer to what you think it does. It's specifically referring to the value of [form input elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefvalue) or [HTML elements' attributes' value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

Here are some other options to try:

#### Use [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

The text, "Test", in your element, is a child called a `textNode`. You can get the text value from any element using `Element.innerText` (so in your case `document.getElementById("test").innerText`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p id="test">Test</p>
    <script>
        let test = document.getElementById("test").innerText; // "Test"
        alert(test)
    </script>
</body>
```

#### Using [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

You can also use `.innerHTML` to get the HTML of an element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p id="test"><b>Test</b></p>
    <script>
        let test = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML; // "<b>Test</b>"
        alert(test)
    </script>
</body>
```

#### Using [Element.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

You can also use `.textContent` to get the "text content" of an element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p id="test"><b>Test</b></p>
    <script>
        let test = document.getElementById("test").textContent; // "<b>Test</b>"
        alert(test)
    </script>
</body>
```

#### innerText vs textContent (as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText)):

> - textContent gets the content of all elements, including  and  elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable” elements.
> - textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements. Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.)
> - Unlike textContent, altering innerText in Internet Explorer (version 11 and below) removes child nodes from the element and permanently destroys all descendant text nodes. It is impossible to insert the nodes again into any other element or into the same element anymore.

Comment: In this use case, neither `innerText` (which is non-standard) or `innerHTML` should be used. `.innerHTML` should only be used when a) there is HTML to be parsed and b) that HTML is under the developer's control. Instead, `.textContent` should be used here. Both of the MDN links you've shown talk about `textContent` in their "Note" at the top of the pages.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Actually I disagree. [`.innerText` is in the WHATWG HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) and ships with [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=innertext), firstly; secondly, `.textContent` returns only "human-readable" content, which is probably what OP wants

Comment: `.innerText` is not in the W3C HTML spec. There has always been areas where the two specs don't align. But, the W3C spec. is the more recognized one, regardless of browser support. I'm not sure what you mean by "human readable", but in the vast majority of use cases, `textContent` is what you want, rather than `.innerText`. In fact, I can honestly say I haven't used `.innerText` in over a decade because `.textContent` has done what was needed.

Comment: Elements that are hidden by CSS or `<script>` content - as noted on MDN

Comment: I don't think you read those docs properly. You said that `.textContent` returns only "human readable" content, but the docs say that's the case for `.innerText`. `.textContent` gives you MORE information than `.innerText` does, which makes is more useful, thus my comments.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. But, no, given the question, I think `.innerText` would be more suitable for the OP

Comment: Just curious, why do you think so? `.textContent` produces the correct results, is more robust, and (in the case of IE) less error prone. `.innerText` is not defined in the W3C standard either. As I said, I haven't seen a use case for `.innerText` since `.textContent` was invented.

Comment: Only in that, as a newcomer to learning to code, it might not be obvious why `.textContent` would return, for example, script tags' content.

Comment: As a newcomer, I would say, don't learn non-standard and potentially hazardous APIs. It's easy enough to read the docs on `.textContent` or any API that a newcomer has to use.

Comment: `.innerText` has shipped with every major browser for as long as I can remember. Agree to disagree at this point, I guess

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `.innerHTML` method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p id="test">Test</p>
    <script>
        let test = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
        alert(test)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: .innerHTML should only be used when a) there is HTML to be parsed and b) that HTML is under the developer's control. Instead, .textContent should be used here.